# How to apply "duplicated" child object?

Tags: modifiers, objects

As you can see I made ChildObject (sphere) a child of ParentObject (arrow), and in object data of the ParentObject I set Duplication/Verts.

That's looking ok to me, but I would like to edit one of "duplicated" spheres. I can not do this right now, because as far as I know I can edit only the ChildObject which will effect all other duplicated spheres, and I don't want that.

**How to apply duplication?**

And also how can I render only duplicated spheres? In current situation I have to render ChildObject in order to render duplitates of ChildObject, but I don't want to render that one out of order sphere, I just want spheres in shape of the arrow...

Please Help!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the make duplicates real function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

[image]